# Custom logo sizes for multiple logos

Tags: functions, logo

I am using

```
add_theme_support('custom-logo', array(
// The logo will be displayed with the following sizes:
    'width' => 200,
    'height' => 200,
));
```

to display a logo image in my sidebar.

in functions.php I have set the size for the large logo:

```
add_theme_support('custom-logo', array(
// The logo will be displayed with the following sizes:
    'width' => 200,
    'height' => 200,
));
```

However, I would also like to use the same logo in the header, but with a size of 80x80px. This means I need to set two different sizes for `the_custom_logo`. Is this possible? If so how?

I have tried using `add_image_size` but I believe this is wrong so I am not really sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to modify the size of the *custom logo* with:

```
// Modify the custom logo size
add_filter( 'image_downsize', 'wpse241257_new_custom_logo_size', 10, 3 );

// Display the custom logo
the_custom_logo();
```

where our filter callback is defined as (*PHP 5.4+*):

```
function wpse241257_new_custom_logo_size( $downsize, $id, $size )
{
    //-------------------
    // Edit to your needs
    $size = [80,80];          // Array of width and height
    // $size = 'thumbnail';   // String value of the image size name
    //-------------------

    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ ); // Important to avoid recursive loop
    return image_downsize( $id, $size );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What does the `, 10, 3 );` numbers do?

Comment: Filter priority = 10  (default) and number of input arguments = 3 for the filter callback  @Arete

Comment: For some reason this code is making my featured images (post thumbnails) 80x80px. I realized this just now. But I am not sure why. Can you help me?

Comment: strange, I don't get that behavior on my vanilla install. Did you modify anything? @Arete